# Creating a new Rails 4 app when I have Rails 3 and rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

My Mac 10.9 is currently set up with Rails 3.x and Ruby 1.9.3.  For a new app I am making, I want to use Rails 4 (or 4.1?) and Ruby 2.x (not sure which version is recommended).  How do I do this with rvm so that I can easily switch back and forth between old and new apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install another ruby version with RVM, like `rvm install ruby 2.1.1` and you can switch with many version `rvm use 1.9.3`

http://rvm.io/rvm/basics

Comment: Or better yet, use rbenv. Less magic, more lightweight. Anyway, the whole point of RVM and rbenv is that you can switch versions.

Comment: rvm install ruby 2.1.1
Version '2.1.1' is ambiguous. Cannot select Ruby implementation/version, please be more specific.

Comment: you must add a patch for install 2.1.1 version example `rvm install ruby 2.1.1-p76`

Comment: rvm install ruby 2.1.1-p76 also throws Version '2.1.1' is ambiguous. Cannot select Ruby implementation/version, please be more specific.
Could not detect ruby version/name for installation, please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
  rvm get head

  rvm reload

  rvm install ruby-2.1.1
```